# "He received his AB from Princeton University with highest honors." Was he the top mathematics student in Princeton University?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

The following sentence is in "About the Author" in this book:

> He received his AB from Princeton University with highest honors, followed by a PhD in Mathematics from the University of California at Berkeley.

Does this mean he was the top mathematics student in Princeton University?
Or does this mean he was one of the best mathematics students in Princeton University?

Comment: Cum laude: with honours, praise. magna cum laude: magna=great. summa cum laude: summa=greatest. I would assume this means that he graduated summa cum laude. None of these are exclusive.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stuartf says, degrees in American universities are typically given "cum laude", which is Latin for "with praise" or "with honors"; "magna cum laude", "with great honors"; or "summa cum laude", "with highest honors". (Or the degree may have none of these -- you just got an ordinary degree.)

Many students could graduate with each of these. Graduating "summa cum laude" or "with highest honors" doesn't mean that you were the best, most accomplished graduate the college ever had. It doesn't even mean that you were the best that year. It does mean that you were among the best that year.

For what it's worth: The student with the highest grade point average for a given year is called the "valedictorian", and #2 is called the "salutatorian". Side note: I recall that when I graduated high school my friends and I discussed the fact that our class valedictorian was probably not the most intelligent, accomplished student in the school: she got high grades because she took easy classes. We thought the #2 student was actually very accomplished and more deserving of honor.

Comment: Jay, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Princeton's website](https://ua.princeton.edu/contents/academic-regulations/graduation-and-honors) states that a degree can be awarded in three categories: with "honors", "high honors", or "highest honors". This is a variant on the system of [Latin honors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_honors#Distinctions) used in many other American universities, which awards bachelor (undergraduate) degrees *cum laude* (with praise), *magna cum laude* (with great praise), or *summa cum laude* (with the highest praise) depending on the student's performance in assessments. Hence "highest honors" is the highest classification for an undergraduate degree at Princeton, given to students who perform very well (perhaps comparable with a "first class degree" in the UK system, although precise standards will vary).

Comment: Stuart F, Thank you very much for your answer.